# Lodash finding a partial uniqueness within array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

The following code, returns an array of unique value from the `data` array. However, what I am trying to achieve is return true if there is a uniqueness found at `value1:value2`. As you can see from the code below `value1:value2:value3` and `value1:value2:value4` match this criteria. A **lodash** technique to produce this functionality would be ideal, however for the sake of understanding a solution I would gladly welcome plain 'ol' javascript.

**NOTE** jQuery and HTML have been included to illustrate my question. The javascript I am after, would be running on NodeJS.

**UPDATE**

Expected output from running the code below would `true` as there is a match between `value1:value2:value3` and `value1:value2:value4` i.e. `value1:value2` exist in both values.

**UPDATE**

Please see the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4zpoaw1/2/) for an example of the output I am after.

**UPDATE**

Included is an example of the output I am after. This is the desired functionality, however I would like a **lodash** way of achieving the same result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    'value1:value2:value3',
    'value1:value2:value4',
    'value5:value6:value7',
    'value1:value2:value3'
    ];
  var partialValueMatch = function(data) {
    var lookup = _.uniqBy(data, function(str){
      return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(':'))
    });
    if(lookup.length < data.length) return true;
    return false;
  }
  var $output = $('#output');
  $output.html(partialValueMatch(data));
});
```

```css
#output {
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better, given a data set what would be the ideal output?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis please see **UPDATE**

Comment: @JagsSparrow 's answer will probably work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)

```
 var data = [
    'value1:value2:value3',
    'value1:value2:value4',
    'value5:value6:value7',
    'value1:value2:value3'
    ];

var output = _.uniqBy(data,function(str){
   return str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(':'))
 });
console.log(output);
console.log('Is duplicates found:',output.length<data.length);
```

This will give you uniq data as below

```
//["value1:value2:value3", "value5:value6:value7"]
//Is duplicates found: true
```

Comment: Awesome and usable for my needs. However, is there any way I could make it `return true`?

Comment: Where need `return true` in output, Plz share output sample with us.

Comment: In your example, the length of the `data` array has changed, so I guess a comparison could be made on the original input array length and the output length, if it's less than the original.. return true.

Comment: Yep, You can get it by comparing input & output data length.

Comment: I have included a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/s4zpoaw1/ to better explain my example, using the method you described.

Comment: I wondered if there was a lodash way of doing it, my question now includes my desired output, please see the last **UPDATE**.

Comment: I guess, they don't have  inbuilt method for this